# how to ensure immutability of class when it is composed of mutable attributes

Tags: java, immutability

To make a class immutable when it consists of mutable attribute(s), we should return defensive copies of the mutable attributes.
Consider below mentioned class

```
class User {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Date dateOfBirth;

// standard getter and setter for firstName and lastName 

public void setdateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth){}
 this.dateOfBirth = new Date(dateOfBirth.getTime());

public Date getDateOfBirth(){
   return new Date(dateOfBirth.getTime());
   }
}
```

Can we say that if date attribute is set and returned using the above mentioned getters and setter method, it would help in creating the class as immutable and would help in saving the internal state of user class for dateOfBirth field?

Comment: You meant to type "to make a class **immutable**", right?

Comment: @jingx: yes, i have edited the question

Comment: @Michael: tx for the answer, could you please shed some light as to what this type of pattern is called ( got your point that providing setter disqualifies it from immutability). Would we just call it a good programming practice to return defensive copy when mutable object is being used in a class

Answer (score 4):

> To create immutable class in java, you have to do following steps.
>
> 1.Declare the class as final so it can’t be extended.
>
> 2.Make all fields private so that direct access is not allowed.
>
> 3.Don’t provide setter methods for variables
>
> 4.Make all mutable fields final so that it’s value can be assigned only once.
>
> 5.Initialize all the fields via a constructor performing deep copy.
>
> 6.Perform cloning of objects in the getter methods to return a copy rather than returning the actual object reference

https://www.journaldev.com/129/how-to-create-immutable-class-in-java

In your case class will look like this

```
public final class User {

  private final String firstName;
  private final String lastName;
  private final Date dateOfBirth;

  public User(String first, String last, Date birth) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last; //Since String objects are immutable no need to copy
    this.dateOfBirth = new Date(birth.getTime()); //Date is mutable so copy parameter to avoid mutation
  }

  public Date getDateOfBirth(){
   return new Date(dateOfBirth.getTime());
  }
}
```

Comment: tx for the reference, i got the point that provides setter in a class disqualifies it from achieving immutability. can you please help me to understand the practice related to setting and returning value for a date attribute in the above fashion